# Alien psychic kid passing as human

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

These books were in my middle school library.  It was a series of at least 2 (possibly more) books about a young man who was an alien.  He passed as human and only a few people knew, including some older man who seemed like a father figure.

Because he was an alien he had ESP-style psychic powers (telekinesis and others).  At some point he uses them to cause or stop or save someone from a car crash.  There was definitely a car or bus accident.

I believe the planet his people were from may have allegedly been a system orbiting a star in the Orion constellation.  It no longer existed, I believe -- I remember specifically the text making a point that the star it had orbited was gone, but that they could still see it up until a certain point in one of the books because speed-of-light, etc.

I should add that I remember it as being pretty much contemporary (roughly set in the 80's or 90's)--not set in the future.  There wasn't, apparently, much space travel or anything (even though there must have been, or how else did he get there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely a series of books by G. Clifton Wisler: *The Antrian Messenger* (1986), *The Seer* (1989), & *The Mind Trap* (1990).

The teenager was an alien; if I recall correctly in the first novel he uses a car crash to fake his own death as agents from the government had become interested in him.  The father figure was a mentor originally from his home world.  He could pass as a human because the only outward difference in his appearance was some sort of double lens in his eye that would only be noticed if a doctor examined him.  He also had powers of telekinesis & telepathy as you mention.

Comment: I am almost positive that's it, even the titles sound familiar.  Gonna go look them up to verify.

Comment: Can't find any text, but every detail I recall lines up with what I've found.  The explosion through the telescope, the old guy, the car accident, being almost identical to humans, having a range of powers...

Answer (score 1):

Is it *Psion (Cat)* and *Catspaw* by Joan D. Vinge?
The omnibus edition is called [Alien Blood](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/235580.Alien_Blood?from_search=true)
It's a very popular YA series about a half human half alien orphan telepath.
And there's a third book called *Dreamfall*

Comment: Nope! I've also read that one, but I still own it, so I know it's not the same one.